# how to retrieve data from mysql using text entered in java swing text box when I press enter button?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, applet

[image]Following is my Java Swing applet code in which I have first field as `employee code` and `text box for entering employee code`, I want to retrieve data of employee from  MySql database when I will enter `employee code` in `text box` after hitting `Enter key` on keyboard and set retrieve data in respective `text boxes` and `combo boxes`. and same to embed it in JSP as applet.

Please help.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class App extends JApplet{

public void start()
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Form");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("");
JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
JButton but_per = new JButton("Personalize");
//JButton button2 = new JButton("Cancel");
Container c;
c=frame.getContentPane();
c.setLayout(null);
JLabel name=new JLabel("Name :");
JLabel compcode=new JLabel("Company Code :");
JLabel cardno=new JLabel("Card Number: ");
JLabel cardtype=new JLabel("Card Type :");
JLabel pin=new JLabel("Pin :");
JLabel bldgrp=new JLabel("Blood Group :");
JLabel empcode=new JLabel("Employee Code :");
JLabel dob=new JLabel("DOB :");
JLabel valupto=new JLabel("Valid Upto :");
JLabel jdate=new JLabel("Joining Date :");
JLabel dept=new JLabel("Department :");
JLabel uid=new JLabel("UID :");
String data []={"A","AB","B","B +","A +","O +","O -"};
JTextField nametxt=new JTextField(10);
JComboBox compcodetxt=new JComboBox();
JTextField cardnumtxt=new JTextField(10);
JTextField cardtypetxt=new JTextField(10);
JTextField pintxt=new JTextField(10);
JComboBox bldgrptxt=new JComboBox(data);
bldgrptxt.setSelectedIndex(5);
JTextField empcodetxt=new JTextField(10);
JTextField dobtxt=new JTextField(10);
JTextField valuptotxt=new JTextField(10);
JTextField jdatetxt=new JTextField(10);
JTextField depttxt=new JTextField(10);
JTextField uidtxt=new JTextField(10);

empcode.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
empcodetxt.setBounds(110, 10, 100, 25);
name.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
nametxt.setBounds(110, 40, 100, 25);
compcode.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 25);
compcodetxt.setBounds(110, 70, 100, 25);
cardno.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 25);
cardnumtxt.setBounds(110, 100, 100, 25);
//pin.setBounds(10, 110, 100, 25);
//pintxt.setBounds(110, 110, 100, 25);
bldgrp.setBounds(10, 130, 100, 25);
bldgrptxt.setBounds(110, 130, 100, 25);
dob.setBounds(10, 160, 100, 25);
dobtxt.setBounds(110, 160, 100, 25);
valupto.setBounds(10, 190, 100, 25);
valuptotxt.setBounds(110, 190, 100, 25);
jdate.setBounds(10, 220, 100, 25);
jdatetxt.setBounds(110, 220, 100, 25);
dept.setBounds(10, 250, 100, 25);
depttxt.setBounds(110, 250, 100, 25);
uid.setBounds(10, 280, 100, 25);
uidtxt.setBounds(110, 280, 100, 25);

but_per.setBounds(10, 340, 120, 25);
//button2.setBounds(10, 70, 75, 25);

c.add(name); c.add(nametxt);
c.add(compcode); c.add(compcodetxt);
c.add(cardno); c.add(cardnumtxt);
c.add(pin); c.add(pintxt);
c.add(bldgrp); c.add(bldgrptxt);
c.add(empcode); c.add(empcodetxt);
c.add(dob); c.add(dobtxt);
c.add(valupto); c.add(valuptotxt);
c.add(jdate); c.add(jdatetxt);
c.add(dept); c.add(depttxt);
c.add(uid); c.add(uidtxt);
c.add(but_per);


//panel.add(button1);
//panel.add(button2);
//frame.add(panel);
frame.setSize(350,400);
//frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void stop(){}

}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.  BTW - what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Andrew: I want to catch employee code entered in first text box and pass that employee code in my query to retrieve data against that employee code and set that data in remaining text boxes.I know how to query database but having problem in catching code entered in text box  once I hit enter key.

Comment: BTW - `public class App extends JApplet{

public void start()
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Form");` 1) Don't launch a frame from an applet, as it will cause all sorts of focus problems. 2) And certainly don't launch a frame from the `start()` method where it will be called every time the browser is restored from minimized!

Answer (score 0):

In your `ActionListener` for that button retrieve the text of the textfield using `textfield.getText()` and then use this value to query database. I'm assuming that you know well how to query database.

Answer (score 0):

Wait! you haven't implemented `ActionListener`!

Do the following:

```
       but_per.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            /// write your code here!
          String a= field.getText();
           System.out.print(a);
         ///or DB code
        }
        });
```

Here is a [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) if you aren't familiar with `Action Listener`

**UPDATE:**

If you want all processing after a key press, you have to implement keybord events,
you can find a tutorial link [here](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes4/c6/s5.html)

Comment: here I will have to press my button which I don't want to implement , once I hit enter key after entering employee code it should catch employee code and pass that code to my query to fetch data against that code and set it in remaining text and combo boxes

Answer (score 0):

This source is the closest workable version of your code I could produce, but it still has many serious problems.

- Using the `start()` method incorrectly.  The method will be called each time the browser is restored from minimized.
- Use of a `null` layout and `setBounds()`.
- A free floating, non modal GUI element will cause focus problems..

Having said that, type a number in the employee code field and hit enter to see something like (screenshot shortened vertically)..

[image: <code>JFrame</code> with <code>JOptionPane</code>]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/* <applet code=App width=400 height=600></applet> */
public class App extends JApplet {

    public void start() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Form");

        ActionListener doDB = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Query the DB off the EDT!");
            }
        };

        // This cannot be done in a sand-boxed applet
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // hides the bottom field..
        //frame.setResizable(false);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("");
        JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
        JButton but_per = new JButton("Personalize");

        Container c;
        c = frame.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        JLabel name = new JLabel("Name :");
        JLabel compcode = new JLabel("Company Code :");
        JLabel cardno = new JLabel("Card Number: ");
        JLabel cardtype = new JLabel("Card Type :");
        JLabel pin = new JLabel("Pin :");
        JLabel bldgrp = new JLabel("Blood Group :");
        JLabel empcode = new JLabel("Employee Code :");
        JLabel dob = new JLabel("DOB :");
        JLabel valupto = new JLabel("Valid Upto :");
        JLabel jdate = new JLabel("Joining Date :");
        JLabel dept = new JLabel("Department :");
        JLabel uid = new JLabel("UID :");
        String data[] = {"A", "AB", "B", "B +", "A +", "O +", "O -"};
        JTextField nametxt = new JTextField(10);
        JComboBox compcodetxt = new JComboBox();
        JTextField cardnumtxt = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField cardtypetxt = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField pintxt = new JTextField(10);
        JComboBox bldgrptxt = new JComboBox(data);
        bldgrptxt.setSelectedIndex(5);
        JTextField empcodetxt = new JTextField(10);
        empcodetxt.addActionListener(doDB);
        JTextField dobtxt = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField valuptotxt = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField jdatetxt = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField depttxt = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField uidtxt = new JTextField(10);

        empcode.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
        empcodetxt.setBounds(110, 10, 100, 25);
        name.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 25);
        nametxt.setBounds(110, 40, 100, 25);
        compcode.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 25);
        compcodetxt.setBounds(110, 70, 100, 25);
        cardno.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 25);
        cardnumtxt.setBounds(110, 100, 100, 25);
        bldgrp.setBounds(10, 130, 100, 25);
        bldgrptxt.setBounds(110, 130, 100, 25);
        dob.setBounds(10, 160, 100, 25);
        dobtxt.setBounds(110, 160, 100, 25);
        valupto.setBounds(10, 190, 100, 25);
        valuptotxt.setBounds(110, 190, 100, 25);
        jdate.setBounds(10, 220, 100, 25);
        jdatetxt.setBounds(110, 220, 100, 25);
        dept.setBounds(10, 250, 100, 25);
        depttxt.setBounds(110, 250, 100, 25);
        uid.setBounds(10, 280, 100, 25);
        uidtxt.setBounds(110, 280, 100, 25);

        but_per.setBounds(10, 340, 120, 25);

        c.add(name);
        c.add(nametxt);
        c.add(compcode);
        c.add(compcodetxt);
        c.add(cardno);
        c.add(cardnumtxt);
        c.add(pin);
        c.add(pintxt);
        c.add(bldgrp);
        c.add(bldgrptxt);
        c.add(empcode);
        c.add(empcodetxt);
        c.add(dob);
        c.add(dobtxt);
        c.add(valupto);
        c.add(valuptotxt);
        c.add(jdate);
        c.add(jdatetxt);
        c.add(dept);
        c.add(depttxt);
        c.add(uid);
        c.add(uidtxt);
        c.add(but_per);

        frame.setSize(350, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void stop() {
    }
}
```